# Core Data dependent property on to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to update a custom property in an NSManagedObject whenever an item that it has a to-many relation to changes.  I've overridden the following methods as prescribed by apple:

```
- (void)addDevicesObject:(Device *)value;
- (void)removeDevicesObject:(Device *)value;
- (void)addDevices:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeDevices:(NSSet *)value;
```

and inside the implementation I add or remove observers on the changed objects.  The problem is my override methods are not called when my bindings based UI makes changes to the data.  How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the custom property is calculated when it is asked for, use +keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey: to trigger update notifications when devices is changed.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if([key isEqualToString:@"MyCustomProperty"]) return [NSSet setWithObject:@"devices"];
    return [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];
}
```

If you want to perform calculations when devices is changed only, then use KVO to get notified when it is changed.

```
//Put this in the various awake... methods
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"devices" options:0 context:nil];
//Put this in the didTurnIntoFault method
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"devices"];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)path ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(object == self && [path isEqualToString:@"devices"]) {
        //Update custom property here
    } else [super observeValueForKeyPath:path ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

Comment: from reading your answer what I have realized that I really need to do is perform the recalculation whenever either devices change or when device.type changes, does that mean I need to observe the type attribute on every device in the collection?

Comment: Basically, yes, but you could use an NSArrayController to do it automatically for you. Bind the controller's content to the devices key, and observe the path arrangedObjects.type on the controller. I can add this to my post if you like.

Comment: See reply from Martin Brugger below, I've personally tried his solution and it's the best so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem I solved in a little [github project](https://github.com/mbrugger/CoreDataDependentProperties)

Using observings to solve the problem is a possible way, still you need to consider many core data specific problems with faulting  (observing a property of a faulting object) and undo/redo/delete. If you want to stay 10.5 compatible the important method awakeFromSnapshotEvent is also missing and you need a workaround to activate observings for undoing delete objects after a context save.

The setter:

```
- (void)setDevices:(NSSet *)newDevices
```

should also be called in bindings if you want to avoid observings which can be complicated.
Setters are NOT called in undo/redo operations! So you should store your dependent value in a core data modeled property.

Comment: Martin this project is EXACTLY what I wanted. I can't believe how easy it is to use your code to manage and update derived properties. I wasn't able to find any concrete example anywhere on the internet and your code just DID it. I can't believe your answer was not ranked or marked as correct. Many, many thanks!!!!!!

Comment: I am really glad to hear someone is actually using the code besides myself. If you need help or find bugs, feel free to contact me.